# Working between Excel files and R: trouble reading data into R

Tags: r, excel, header-files, read.csv

I am reading in thousands of files. Each file has 5 rows of information, then a header row, then the data. Each file contains a different number of columns with different column names and I need to record the column names in order to know how to process it. Unfortunately when I read in the file with this:

```
temp.data <- read.csv(temp[i],header=TRUE,sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip= 5)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

The reason this happens is that the number of delimiters in the header row is one less than the number of delimiters in the data rows. I know this because if you count the fields - you can see the header has 10 and the data has 11. Example below.

```
count.fields(temp[i],sep=",",skip = 5)
[1] 10 11 11 11 11 11
```

If I knew all the files were formatted the same, then I would just input my own header columns and read the data from line 6, but because I need to know what each column is named so that I know how to use this I need to record the column headers coming in. How can I do this? An example file is below.

```
--Meta Data--                                   
Start Time(UTC) LoggerName  Pck Vin                     
7/22/2017 18:57 9160-06A0                               

--Raw Data--                                    
Timestamp(UTC)  Air Conditioning Power[Watts]   C2 Input Voltage[V] HV Battery Current[A]   HV Battery SOC[%]   HV Battery Voltage[V]   Is Driving[bool]    OAT[DegC]   Odometer[kilometers]    Vehicle Speed[km/h]
7/22/2017 18:57 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7/22/2017 18:57 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7/22/2017 18:58 1700    13.21100044 0.600036621 94  394.7399902 1   37  62842.47656 33.07193375
7/22/2017 18:59 3300    13.04199982 -28 94  392.7399902 1   37  62843.01172 16.33480072
7/22/2017 19:00 3000    13.07600021 -10.09997559    93  393.9799805 1   36.5    62843.73047 0
```

In excel the column headers and the columns of data line up, so I dont know what is happening in this case. I am guessing that it is reading the date/time column as two columns.

If that is the case, how can I add another col header titled 'date' in at the front of the other column headers?

Comment: Your code is using sep="," but there are no commas in what the question claims to be lines from the file.

Comment: Try `read.table` with `row.names` option?

Comment: Are you trying to create a list containing all file column names or is your problem that you cannot read in files because the formatting is corrupt?